# Syntax errors in ajax calls/javascript not appearing in rails application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, firebug, syntax-error

Say I have something like this in my js.erb file.

```
$(div_id + <%= @line_num %>).html("<%=j render :partial => "quant_change_form" %>");
```

That works fine but if I have a syntax error like say (i.e. method does not exist):

```
$(div_id + <%= @line_num %>).htmlabcd("<%=j render :partial => "quant_change_form" %>");
```

I don't get a syntax error in my editor (I'm using RubyMine) and I don't get an error in Firebug.  It simply doesn't work without telling me why.  Isn't this the recommended way you're supposed to make an ajax call in rails?

Comment: I wouldn't expect an error like .htmlabcd() to be highlighted in a source editor or IDE, since it's not a syntax error, but I would expect a runtime error in the browser when you try to run that code. I don't have Firebug, but in the built-in FF console I got the error "$(div_id + 1).htmlabcd is not a function" when I tried something similar here: http://jsfiddle.net/NAEn6 (I did have to click the "JS" button in the FF console because by default it was only logging "Net" activities - make sure the equivalent setting in Firebug is turned on).

Comment: this seems to address my problem: http://coderwall.com/p/yujrja but I can't use his troubleshooting method because I'm loading a partial

Comment: That CoderWall post says that async code won't show errors in the log, but that's not true. At least, I don't have a problem getting errors in the console for asnyc functions. The browser doesn't know or care what's happening with the server-side code. If it doesn't work for you with Firebug try another debugging tool, e.g., Chrome's built-in tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after doing a bit more searching, I found a reasonable solution.  For some reason, if there's an error in a js.erb file, it will fail silently and there will be no indication of an error in Firebug.

The solution to this problem is outlined here:

http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-js-erb-remote-response-not-executing/

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't get an syntax error because the syntax is valid
2. If you don't get an error with firebug it means your code is not executed and `htmlabcd` is a valid method name.

Comment: okay, so it's not a syntax error.  But it is a runtime error which should appear in firebug. But even with a syntax error like leaving out a semicolon or putting in a random set of characters, I get nothing!

Comment: @yiinewbie as semicolons are optional it won't produce an syntax error if you omit them. Maybe your javascript file isn't loaded at all?

Comment: The javascript file definitely loaded because when I remove the errors, it works fine.  I believe this problem is related to using the rails way of making ajax requests.

Comment: @yiinewbie Firebug has filter options that may result in no JS errors being logged. Check the "console" drop-down for options. Regarding the possibility of a problem with the Ajax request: _what_ Ajax request? Your question doesn't show any JS Ajax functionality...

Comment: Yes, I have that filter on.  I believe the problem has to do with errors not being recognized in js.erb files as it's described here http://coderwall.com/p/yujrja I just thought there must be an easier way to debug than what is described there